# Inserting a node into range doesn't work from change event

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, range, selection, contenteditable

I'm trying to set an anchor to a specific position inside a `ContentEditable` component. If I call the method from a button click it works fine but if I call in from the onChange method nothing happens.

```
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<any>();
    const [html, setHTML] = React.useState<string>('');

    const addMenu = () => {
        const selection = window.getSelection();
        let range = selection?.getRangeAt(0);
        if (selection && range) {
            range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
            range.deleteContents();
            const anchor = document.createElement('span');
            range.insertNode(anchor);
            setTimeout(() => {
                setAnchorEl(anchor);
            }, 2000);
        }
    };

    const handleChange = (evt) => {
        addMenu();
    };

    return(
        <>
            <ContentEditable
                    css={{
                        border: `1px solid ${Colors.primary};`,
                        height: '500px;',
                        width: '500px;',
                    }}
                    tagName="span"
                    innerRef={ref}
                    html={html} // innerHTML of the editable div
                    disabled={false} // use true to disable editing
                    onChange={handleChange} // handle innerHTML change
            />
            <button
                type="button"
                key="menu"
                onMouseDown={() => {
                    addMenu();
                }}
            >
                Menu
            </button>
            <Menu open={open} anchorEl={anchorEl}>
               {...someContent}
            </Menu>
        <>
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go with "react way" and use ref: [code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-menu-after-element-ju7eq1)

```
  const editableRef = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
  const buttonRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState<HTMLSpanElement>();
  const [html, setHTML] = useState('Test html');

  const addMenu = useCallback((ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>) => {
    const anchor = document.createElement('span');
    anchor.innerText = 'Anchor element';

    ref.current?.after(anchor);

    setAnchorEl(anchor);
  }, []);

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    (event: ContentEditableEvent) => {
      setHTML(event.target.value);
      addMenu(editableRef);
    },
    [addMenu],
  );

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    addMenu(buttonRef);
  };

  console.log(anchorEl, 'anchorEl');

  return (
    <>
      <ContentEditable
        innerRef={editableRef}
        style={contentStyle}
        tagName="span"
        html={html}
        disabled={false}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />

      <button
        ref={buttonRef}
        type="button"
        key="menu"
        onClick={handleButtonClick}
      >
        Menu
      </button>
    </>
  );
```